# Value of the variable becomes empty when accessed outside the function in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, function, coding-style

I have the following code :

for(var index in workload.elements)
        {
            var arr = [];
            var resourceIdentifiers = {};
            var elementinfo = {};
            var metadataModified = {};

```
        elementinfo = workload.elements[index];


        arr[index] = workload.elements[index].uri;
        if(workload.elements[index].parameters.imageUri)
        {
            arr.push(workload.elements[index].parameters.imageUri);
        }
        resourceIdentifiers = arr.join(',');
        console.log('uri' + resourceIdentifiers);

        // connects with mysql and fetch data
        mysql.elementlevelpricing(resourceIdentifiers, function(result){

        elementlevelpricingSummary = JSON.stringify(result,null,2);
        console.log('resultin' + elementlevelpricingSummary);

        });

        console.log('resultout' + JSON.stringify(elementlevelpricingSummary,null,2))

    }
```

The value of the variable elementlevelpricingSummary becomes empty as {} when accessed outside the called function mysql.elementlevelpricing().

Comment: are you setting the variable elementlevelpricingSummary outside the function before executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to `mysql.elementlevelpricing` is an asynchronous callback, so it is actually running after the `console.log` line below it.  You'll want to do anything you need the data for in the callback itself.

Comment: i thought the node js in similar way as C#

Comment: How can i build a array from the above asynchronous call

Comment: @Prem I'm not really sure what you're asking.  You should open another question about it.